# Facebook API - Using javascript sdk and searching public posts for hashtags

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'd like to bypass the login and run a hashtag search on public posts to return a value of the posts and if possible, the number of total likes.

Is this possible?

I have setup the javascript SDK, but haven't seen any documentation referring to my issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Searches for public Posts require an User Access Token, see docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/#access_tokens

So, you'll have to do soemthing like this:

```
GET /search?q={your_urlencoded_hashtag}&type=post&access_token={your_user_access_token}
```

Comment: Thanks Tobi do you have a code example starting with the fb-root div?

Comment: No, just use the FB.api() method of the JS SDK..,