# Need help on employing Graph Search parameters for hashtag query on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The problem:

I want to find public posts that contain two hashtags (like #games & #movies). The graph search does not work with hashtags apparently. Do you know a way to use the Graph API to set up a query that can help me find those particular postings.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no API for hashtag search as of yet; only thing you can do is the normal search features of the API and search for them as text content.

Comment: so you would just employ a multiple keyword search? Should I include the '#' inside the query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard Search API for Posts as described in the answer here:

[Facebook API - Using javascript sdk and searching public posts for hashtags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475827/facebook-api-using-javascript-sdk-and-searching-public-posts-for-hashtags/22476530#22476530)

For example,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23selfie&type=post&access_token={user_access_token}
```

works for me.

Comment: thanks! i tried this, but unfortunately i will not get any results even though i know that the particular hashtag should give me around 50 returns. this is the query i use:

`search?q=%23hashtag&type=post&access_token=token`

Comment: Are you using an User Access Token as https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search states?

Comment: it seems it does not store any information to my particular hashtag.. i receive `{
   "data": [
      
   ]
}`the acces_token is correct but maybe i need different permissions?

Comment: Accessing Search API is not a matter of permissions for public posts, only important is that the Access Token type is a User one. Did you try the link I added in my answer with a User Access Token?

Comment: yep. did work with your link, and the hashtag "selfie", sadly just not with the hashtag i am looking for :(

Comment: Will you name the hashtag, or is this confident?