# Embed Facebook Stream Filtered By Hashtags

Tags: facebook, stream, hashtag

I want to embed a stream of facebook posts onto a web page that is comprised of posts all around facebook containing a specific hash tag, but I'm not quite sure how to go about it.  I had to do the same with twitter and instagram, but those were all fairly easy to accomplish.  I'm just kind of looking for the best option right now, not so much on specifics.  I've seen a couple of times the graph api for facebook as an option, but every time I see those they seem to be from a year ago, so not sure if it's out of date or if there is a better option out by now.  Any recommendations on ways to go about it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer here on how you can use the Search API for hashtags:

[Need help on employing Graph Search parameters for hashtag query on facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340877/need-help-on-employing-graph-search-parameters-for-hashtag-query-on-facebook/23342041#23342041)

Basically, you can call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23selfie&type=post&access_token={user_access_token}
```

Be aware that you have to use v1.0 of the Graph API, because in v2.0 searching for public posts will no longer be possible (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_graph_api):

> Public post search is no longer available.
>   (/search?type=post&q=foobar)

Graph API v1.0 will only be available until 30th of April, 2015.

Comment: How would I go about making that same search with the java sdk?  Currently this is what I've got:
`FB.api('/search?', {q: '%23honored', type: 'post', access_token: {user_access_token}}, function(response){if(!response || response.error){alert("error");}else{alert("non-error");}});`

All I get in the test console FB provides for it's JavaScript SDK is just my line of code back, no alerts.

Comment: You mean JavaScript SDK? There's no Java SDK afaik... I updated my answer. You replaced {user_access_token} with a real Access Token, right?

Comment: Yeah, meant Javascript sdk, that was my fault.  I've got it grabbing the data and displaying it, now it's mostly just front end stuff, so thanks for the help :)

Comment: If my answer helped you please accept it. Glad that you got it to work.

Comment: An update to this answer please! Documentations are still a mess!!

Comment: @SiddhantRimal Not sure what you're up to. This functionality has been deprecated since v2.0 as the answer states. If you want to complain for FBs's documentation, FB would be the right place to do so

Comment: @Tobi So, it is not possible to get facebook feed by hashtag ? such as #nutrition or #tbt ?

Comment: No. As said, this isn't possible